# Get exact YouTube Subscribers

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API to build a live sub counter but as of now, YouTube has made some changes to their API and it now abbreviates the subscribers.

For example: if you use it on PewDiePie's channel it returns
`subscriberCount: 10200000`

I want it to return the exact number of subscribers.

Is there any other API or any way to circumvent this abbreviation?

This is the Request I'm making
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key`

Comment: Updated it to show the format

Comment: What do the api docs say?

Comment: IIRC, youtube removed the ability to get the live sub count (see: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/6543166?hl=en) - hence why you now see sites like social blade not functioning correctly